# Variable date not working in linux cron

Tags: linux, cron

I am having an issue that I can not find any information for while doing an extensive google search.

I have a linux cron, running via crontab, that works great until I try to add a variable date to the title of the file. BUT.. When I run the same command outside the cron, just from the command line, it works fine..  Also, the cron does work if I take out the date part.

Command line code that works:

```
sudo mysqldump -h mysql.url.com  -u user -pPassword intravet sites | gzip > /mnt/disk2/database_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

Cron that works:

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -h mysql.url.com -u user -pPassword intravet sites | gzip > /mnt/disk2/database.sql.gz
```

Cron that DOESN'T work:

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -h mysql.url.com -u user -pPassword intravet sites | gzip > /mnt/disk2/database_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

I am not understanding why I can not use the date function while inside a cron?
Everything I find says I can, but in practice, I can not.

Server details:
Ubuntu 12.04.5

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: From the man page: `A "%" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to use escaping `%` sign

```
* * * * * touch /tmp/foo_`date '+\%m-\%d-\%Y'`.txt
```

Result:

```
[root@linux tmp]# ls -l /tmp/foo_*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 18 02:17 /tmp/foo_04-18-2015.txt
```

Comment: Neither of these work, I did some research and found out that shell is not, by default, accessible from the cron tab. I still have not solved the issue, but I believe this to be the cause.

Comment: what do you mean shell isn't accessible from crontab? cron use default `SHELL=/bin/bash` variable

Comment: Ok.. So my shell path was incorrect, THEN adding backslash to escape fixed my issue! Thank you guys so much..

Comment: if you find answer is help full then please click on `Answer` to get point

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the backticks with `$()` and escaping your `%`s, such as:

```
15 2 * * * root mysqldump -h mysql.url.com -u user -pPassword intravet sites | gzip > /mnt/disk2/database_$(date '+\%m-\%d-\%Y').sql.gz
```

I only mention removing the backticks because you will end up having all kinds of escaping problems later in your coding endeavours. Stick with using `$()` for command substitution.